# Hibernate Indirect JNDI binding on WebSphere 9

Tags: hibernate, binding, websphere, jndi

I have a problem with the datasource indirect jndi binding on websphere.

I added in my *web.xml* the resource:

```
<resource-ref>
    <description>Data Source JNDI</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/RESOURCE_L</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
</resource-ref>
```

in my *ibm-web-bnd.xml* the resource-ref:

```
<resource-ref name="jdbc/RESOURCE_L" binding-name="jdbc/DATAS_ON_WAS" />
```

and in my *persistence.xml* the jta-data-source:

```
<provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
<jta-data-source>java:comp/env/jdbc/RESOURCE_L</jta-data-source>
```

When the application starts-up I have this error:

```
 ERROR IdTableHelper:94 - Unable to use JDBC Connection to create Statement
java.sql.SQLException: Unsupported use of GenericConnection.  A GenericConnection is provided during application start when creating an EntityManagerFactory for a persistence unit which has configured one of its datasource to be in the component naming context; java:comp/env. During application start, the component naming context will not exist, and the correct datasource cannot be determined. When the persistence unit is used, the proper datasource and connection will be obtained and used.
    at com.ibm.ws.jpa.management.GenericConnection.unsupportedUseSQLException(GenericConnection.java:636)
    at com.ibm.ws.jpa.management.GenericConnection.createStatement(GenericConnection.java:144)
    at org.hibernate.hql.spi.id.IdTableHelper.executeIdTableCreationStatements(IdTableHelper.java:77)
    at org.hibernate.hql.spi.id.global.GlobalTemporaryTableBulkIdStrategy.finishPreparation(GlobalTemporaryTableBulkIdStrategy.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.hql.spi.id.global.GlobalTemporaryTableBulkIdStrategy.finishPreparation(GlobalTemporaryTableBulkIdStrategy.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.hql.spi.id.AbstractMultiTableBulkIdStrategyImpl.prepare(AbstractMultiTableBulkIdStrategyImpl.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:303)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:467)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:939)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:149)
    at com.ibm.ws.jpa.management.JPAPUnitInfo.createEMFactory(JPAPUnitInfo.java:1161)
    at com.ibm.ws.jpa.management.JPAPUnitInfo.initialize(JPAPUnitInfo.java:984)
    at com.ibm.ws.jpa.management.JPAPxmlInfo.extractPersistenceUnits(JPAPxmlInfo.java:240)
    at com.ibm.ws.jpa.management.JPAScopeInfo.processPersistenceUnit(JPAScopeInfo.java:115)
    at com.ibm.ws.jpa.management.JPAApplInfo.addPersistenceUnits(JPAApplInfo.java:147)
    at com.ibm.ws.jpa.management.SharedJPAComponentImpl.startingModule(SharedJPAComponentImpl.java:322)
    at com.ibm.ws.jpa.management.JPAComponentImpl.startingDeployedModule(JPAComponentImpl.java:786)
    at com.ibm.ws.jpa.management.JPAComponentImpl.startingDeployedApplication(JPAComponentImpl.java:691)
    at com.ibm.ws.jpa.management.JPAComponentImpl.stateChanged(JPAComponentImpl.java:551)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl$ComparableDeployedObjectListener.stateChanged(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2652)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.stateChanged(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1178)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectEvent(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1561)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.setState(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:320)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1144)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:800)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplicationDynamically(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1450)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2311)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:436)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:379)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:127)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$1.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:654)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5574)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5700)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:612)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1340)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:83)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor36.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:287)
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean$4.run(RequiredModelMBean.java:1263)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:673)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1257)
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:1096)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:831)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:813)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1350)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:1243)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.sync.StartDeploymentTask.startDeployment(StartDeploymentTask.java:249)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.sync.StartDeploymentTask.fullAppUpdate(StartDeploymentTask.java:121)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.sync.StartDeploymentTask.performTask(StartDeploymentTask.java:109)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.sync.AppBinaryProcessor$ExpandApp.expand(AppBinaryProcessor.java:1770)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.sync.AppBinaryProcessor.postProcessSynchronousExt(AppBinaryProcessor.java:811)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.bla.sync.BLABinaryProcessor.postProcess(BLABinaryProcessor.java:599)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.bla.sync.BLABinaryProcessor.onChangeCompletion(BLABinaryProcessor.java:476)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.bla.sync.BinaryProcessorWrapper.onChangeCompletion(BinaryProcessorWrapper.java:109)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.repository.FileRepository.postNotify(FileRepository.java:1938)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.repository.FileRepository.update(FileRepository.java:1442)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.repository.client.LocalConfigRepositoryClient.update(LocalConfigRepositoryClient.java:189)
    at com.ibm.ws.sm.workspace.impl.WorkSpaceMasterRepositoryAdapter.update(WorkSpaceMasterRepositoryAdapter.java:667)
    at com.ibm.ws.sm.workspace.impl.RepositoryContextImpl.update(RepositoryContextImpl.java:1998)
    at com.ibm.ws.sm.workspace.impl.RepositoryContextImpl.synch(RepositoryContextImpl.java:1946)
    at com.ibm.ws.sm.workspace.impl.WorkSpaceImpl.synch(WorkSpaceImpl.java:549)
    at com.ibm.ws.console.core.action.SyncWorkSpaceAction$1.run(SyncWorkSpaceAction.java:284)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5574)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5700)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
    at com.ibm.ws.console.core.action.SyncWorkSpaceAction.execute(SyncWorkSpaceAction.java:288)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(Unknown Source)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1235)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:779)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:478)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:143)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:96)
    at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.setUpCommandAssistance(WSCUrlFilter.java:971)
    at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.continueStoringTaskState(WSCUrlFilter.java:518)
    at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.doFilter(WSCUrlFilter.java:339)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:197)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:90)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:969)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1109)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:4217)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.handleRequest(WebAppImpl.java:2208)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1030)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1817)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:382)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:465)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:532)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:318)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:289)
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink.determineNextChannel(SSLConnectionLink.java:1187)
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink$MyReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLConnectionLink.java:694)
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1833)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1909)
```

After this exception the persistence unit resource is correctly loaded

```
INFO  LogHelper:31 - HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: mypersistence
    ...]
```

and the application seems to work well.

I'd like to understand why there is this exception and how to solve thi issue.
Any ideas?

Thank you so mutch

Answer (score 2):

What you are seeing there is Hibernate throwing an Exception trying to use GenericConnection, which is a WebSphere internal mock-up of java.sql.Connection.  You see, when WebSphere is starting an application, it must register Class Transformers as early as possible in the application start process, because once a class has been loaded by the application ClassLoader it is no longer eligible for further transformation (JPA persistence providers may enhance persistence-capable classes and add additional methods and fields necessary for internal operation).  A Class Transformer can only be obtained by bootstrapping an EntityManagerFactor which is then registered with the application ClassLoader, which passes any class loaded thereafter through the transformer before it is made available to the runtime.

The problem is, at this time during the application start up phase, the resource-ref bindings have not yet been established.  So persistence units which use java:comp/env references in their  and  definitions have a dependency on a resource which is not yet resolvable.

To work around this problem, for persistence units that use java:comp/env datasources, WebSphere bootstraps an EntityManagerFactory specifically just for collecting a Class Transformer (so it wouldn't be used to create EntityManagers that service application injection, which would normally be the case if data sources with global JNDI names were used) and if the JPA persistence provider asks for a DataSource (which is normally the case, to determine the database vendor), it provides a mock DataSource, the GenericDataSource that you see in your log.  OpenJPA and Eclipselink don't produce an error, but Hibernate does.

The reason that your application still works, is because this EntityManagerFactory is only used for obtaining and registering a Class Transformer, it is not used to provide EntityManagers for application injection.  Basically, for every component context with its own resource ref bindings (that is, a EJB Session Bean, a web module, etc), a new EntityManagerFactory is created which looks up the DataSources within that component's context.

That is why, despite the error in the log, your application still works.

Comment: Thanks @fyrewyld...very kind! is there a way to avoid this exception?

Comment: If there is, the answer would be found in Hibernate's documentation.  They are not throwing an Exception that bubbles back to JPAPUnitInfo.createEMFactory() (if it did, I would expect that would crater application start), so I imagine that they are catching their own Exception and logging it to Sys-Out/Err.  There's nothing we can do about that.

Comment: Thank you so match @fyrewyld. Can I ask you another question? is the above configuration the correct way to implement an indirect JNDI binding in WAS 9 for a Datasource?

Comment: Yes, if you do not want your persistence unit to rely on global JNDI names, then a resource ref using java:comp/env/ is the only way to go.